# How to created nested arrays from a nest of arrays?

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops, javascript-objects

I'm looking to return an array of objects which contains a sub array of objects.

The data I am extracting from contains an array of 'projects' with a bunch of properties and within this array there is an array of 'work items'. I want to loop/map through the 'projects' array and return a new array of objects and within that there will be a 'subtasks' property which needs to contain another array of objects which has been developed from the 'work items' array within the 'projects' array.

Below is where I have got to so far. This is not what I want as I need the main object to just be created when it loops through the projects and then the 'subtasks' array to be created when it loops through the 'work items'. I tried putting the overarching object above the 'return project.workItems.map....' line but I was getting syntax errors.

See below this code for an example of the expected output.

```
  let newProjects1 = projects.map((project, index) => {

  return project.workItems.map((workItem) => {
    return {
      TaskID: index,
      ProjectNo: project.projectNumber,
      TaskName: project.projectTitle,
      StartDate: new Date("11/11/2024"),
      EndDate: new Date(project.projectEnd),
      subtasks: [
        {
          TaskID: index,
          TaskName: workItem.name,
          StartDate: new Date("11/11/2024"),
          Duration: 80,
          Progress: 150,
        },
      ],
    };
  })
;
```

});

The final output needs to look something like this

```
  [
{
  TaskID: 1,
  ProjectNo: "29895",
  TaskName: "Stoneybridge WTW",
  StartDate: new Date(projects[0].projectStart),
  EndDate: new Date(projects[0].projectEnd),
  subtasks: [
    {
      TaskID: 1.1,
      TaskName: "Sodium Carbonate",
      StartDate: new Date(projects[0].projectStart),
      Duration: 4,
      Progress: 150,
      comments: "unlucky",
      subtasks: [
        {
          TaskID: 1.11,
          TaskName: "Design",
          StartDate: new Date(projects[0].projectStart),
          Duration: 30,
          Progress: 150,
        },
        {
          TaskID: 1.12,
          TaskName: "Workshop",
          StartDate: new Date(projects[0].projectStart),
          Duration: 30,
          Progress: 150,
        },
        {
          TaskID: 1.13,
          TaskName: "Site",
          StartDate: new Date(projects[0].projectStart),
          Duration: 30,
          Progress: 150,
        },
      ],
    },]
```

This is the input data i.e. the 'projects' array, which contains the 'workItems' array. This is just one of the objects in the 'projects' array

```
 [{
"projectNumber": 26278,
"projectTitle": "Ifon WTW",
"chemicals": ["sodium hypochlorite", "sodium hydroxide", "pacl"],
"projectStatus": "site survey",
"siteType": "SR",
"location": "Glasgow",
"contractType": "construction",
"designLead": "Craig Garvie",
"projectManager": "Isaac Stanton",
"projectType": "Other",
"spm": "Mark Tench",
"client": "Yorkshire Water",
"comments": "project going swimmingly",
"projectStart": "12/20/2022",
"projectEnd": "07/28/2024",
"createdAt": "2022-11-22T07:43:42Z",
"updatedAt": "2023-04-09T10:13:14Z",
"equipment": [
  { "name": "kiosk", "count": 2 },
  { "name": "tanker fill point", "count": 1 },
  { "name": "dosing skid", "count": 1 },
  { "name": "POA catchpot", "count": 1 },
  { "name": "Low Point Catchpot", "count": 0 },
  { "name": "MCC", "count": 1 }
],
"workItems": [
  {
    "name": "work Item 1",
    "siteSurveyStart": "11/29/2022",
    "siteSurveyEnd": "01/25/2023",
    "designStart": "02/14/2023",
    "designEnd": "03/06/2023",
    "workShopStart": "04/24/2023",
    "workShopEnd": "05/05/2023",
    "rsePremisesStart": "06/24/2023",
    "rsePremisesEnd": "07/09/2023",
    "siteStart": "08/20/2023",
    "siteEnd": "09/13/2023"
  },
  {
    "name": "work Item 2",
    "siteSurveyStart": "11/02/2022",
    "siteSurveyEnd": "01/05/2023",
    "designStart": "02/02/2023",
    "designEnd": "03/24/2023",
    "workShopStart": "04/11/2023",
    "workShopEnd": "05/19/2023",
    "rsePremisesStart": "06/19/2023",
    "rsePremisesEnd": "07/17/2023",
    "siteStart": "08/20/2023",
    "siteEnd": "09/23/2023"
  }
],
"chemical": [{ "name": "sodium carbonate" }, { "name": "sulphuric acid" }],
"projectPersonnel": [
  { "name": "daniel carey" },
  { "name": "erin donnelly" },
  { "name": "craig garvie" },
  { "name": "ryan watson" },
  { "name": "lewis scott" },
  { "name": "jack overfield" },
  { "name": "fidel hernandez" }
]
```

}]

Comment: It's all well and good to show the "expected output" ... but it's going to be tricky to tell you why your code is wrong without knowing the "input"

Comment: @Blob, more context is required to be able to help you… What are project and index parameters?

Comment: Hi guys, apologies. I've now added one of the objects in the 'projects' array, which contains the 'workItems' array at the bottom of my question. Please let me know if that is still unclear. Thanks

Comment: Please visit [help], take [tour] to see what and [ask]. Do some research, search for related topics on SO; if you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output, preferably in a [Stacksnippet](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To have this output, you can use a combination of the `map` function to create the nested structure. Here's an example of how you can modify your code to achieve this:

```
let newProjects = projects.map((project, index) => {
    return {
        TaskID: index + 1,
        ProjectNo: project.projectNumber,
        TaskName: project.projectTitle,
        StartDate: new Date(project.projectStart),
        EndDate: new Date(project.projectEnd),
        subtasks: project.workItems.map((workItem, subIndex) => {
            return {
                TaskID: index + 1 + '.' + (subIndex + 1),
                TaskName: workItem.name,
                StartDate: new Date(project.projectStart),
                Duration: 30,
                Progress: 150,
                subtasks: workItem.subtasks.map((subtask, subtaskIndex) => {
                    return {
                        TaskID: index + 1 + '.' + (subIndex + 1) + '.' + (subtaskIndex + 1),
                        TaskName: subtask.name,
                        StartDate: new Date(project.projectStart),
                        Duration: 30,
                        Progress: 150,
                    };
                }),
            };
        }),
    };
});
```

This code maps through the `projects` array and creates a new object for each project. Within each project object, it uses the `map` function again to create the `subtasks` array based on the `workItems` array.

Make sure to replace Duration, and Progress with the actual properties from your data model.

Comment: That's done the trick. Thanks very much, really appreciate that.

Comment: A [mcve] would be nice